# What are abbreviations used in electrical engineering?

Tags: discussion

This question is meant to be a glossary of abbreviations used in electrical engineering.

Some abbreviations are very common and universal, and are therefore acceptable to use on this site.  Others are quite localized or pet abbreviations used by individuals without a wide following, so are not acceptable on this site.  One purpose of this question is to list all abbreviations so that others have a chance to decode them if encountered, but thru voting also show which ones are acceptable to use in a wide international context or not.

So here are some rules to make this question work:

Each answer must only be for ONE abbreviation.

This will be community wiki, so only ONE answer for each abbreviation.  If you want to expand on a description, edit the existing answer for that abbreviation.

This is going to get long, so consistant formatting will help.  For each answer (abbreviation), start with just the abbreviation within HTML "h1" and "/h1" tags on a line by itself.

Upvote answers for abbreviations you think would be acceptable to use in a post on this site without any expansion or explanation.

Downvote abbreviations (answers) you think should not be used "bare" on this site.  This will be community-wiki, so nobody will loose reputation as a result.  In this special case, you are voting on the universality of the abbreviation, not on the quality of the writeup.  If you don't like the write up, fix it instead.

---

## INDEX

**`A` -** [A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108816/8627/)(2) [AC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109187/8627/)(7) [ADC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108555/8627/)(15) [ALU](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109063/8627/)(3) [AM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108828/8627/)(7) [ASCII](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108533/8627/)(12) [ASIC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108577/8627/)(6) [ASK](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109781/8627/)(1) [AWG](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108612/8627/)(7)

**`B` -** [BCD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108665/8627/)(5) [BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108529/8627/)(16) [BLDC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108726/8627/)(4) [BNC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108625/8627/)(6) [BPF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108846/8627/)(1) [BW](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108653/8627/)(3)

**`C` -** [CAD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108539/8627/)(5) [CAN](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108563/8627/)(7) [CC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108656/8627/)(1) [CC-II](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109885/8627/)(-1) [CCCS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108657/8627/)(1) [CCD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108543/8627/)(6) [CMOS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108523/8627/)(16) [CMRR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109864/8627/)(1) [COG](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109246/8627/)(0) [CPLD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108621/8627/)(4) [CPM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109150/8627/)(-1) [CPU](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108825/8627/)(7) [CRO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109785/8627/)(-1)

**`D` -** [DAC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108548/8627/)(15) [DC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109182/8627/)(7) [DEMUX](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109193/8627/)(2) [DFT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109185/8627/)(2) [DIP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108604/8627/)(5) [DLL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108834/8627/)(2) [DMA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108559/8627/)(7) [DRC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108591/8627/)(3) [DSO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109788/8627/)(3) [DSP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108561/8627/)(13) [DTFT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109189/8627/)(0) [DVD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108568/8627/)(-10) [DVM/DMM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108660/8627/)(4)

**`E` -** [ECL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108638/8627/)(4) [EDA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108542/8627/)(6) [EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108787/8627/)(7) [EEPROM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108572/8627/)(13) [EMC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108537/8627/)(3) [EMS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108567/8627/)(-7) [EOS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108659/8627/)(0) [EPROM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109248/8627/)(3) [ESD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108534/8627/)(9)

**`F` -** [F](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108819/8627/)(2) [FDNR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109889/8627/)(-3) [FET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108527/8627/)(17) [FFC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109244/8627/)(2) [FFT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109181/8627/)(6) [FIFO/LIFO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108574/8627/)(7) [FM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108829/8627/)(7) [FPGA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108575/8627/)(9) [FSK](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109784/8627/)(1) [FSM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108576/8627/)(4)

**`G` -** [GBW](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108654/8627/)(5) [GIC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109886/8627/)(-1) [GND](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108643/8627/)(16) [GPIO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108535/8627/)(9) [GPS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108578/8627/)(4)

**`H` -** [H](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108820/8627/)(2) [HDTV](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108580/8627/)(-11) [HF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108843/8627/)(4) [hFE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109325/8627/)(2) [HPF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108850/8627/)(2) [HVSP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108731/8627/)(-1) [Hz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108709/8627/)(3)

**`I` -** [i](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109832/8627/)(-1) [I/P](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108812/8627/)(-7) [I2S](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109313/8627/)(1) [IC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108582/8627/)(11) [IF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108847/8627/)(4) [IFT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109190/8627/)(1) [IGBT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108684/8627/)(9) [IGFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108682/8627/)(0) [ISP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108637/8627/)(4) [I²C](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108550/8627/)(13)

**`J` -** [j](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109831/8627/)(-1) [JFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108553/8627/)(10) [JTAG](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108585/8627/)(7)

**`K` -** [KCL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108848/8627/)(6) [KVL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108849/8627/)(6)

**`L` -** [LCD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108546/8627/)(17) [LED](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108530/8627/)(19) [LF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108839/8627/)(3) [LPF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108844/8627/)(4) [LSB, MSB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109799/8627/)(2) [LUT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108668/8627/)(5) [LVD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109250/8627/)(-1) [LVDS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108639/8627/)(5) [LVDT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108646/8627/)(0) [LVS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108664/8627/)(-2)

**`M` -** [MCU](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108614/8627/)(6) [MEMS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108586/8627/)(6) [MIDI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108587/8627/)(4) [MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108541/8627/)(17) [MPU](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108616/8627/)(-1) [ms](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108712/8627/)(2) [MUX](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109188/8627/)(6)

**`N` -** [NEXT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108866/8627/)(-6) [NPN](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108524/8627/)(12) [NTSC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109322/8627/)(0) [NVM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108573/8627/)(0)

**`O` -** [O/P](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108813/8627/)(-7) [OCXO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108857/8627/)(2) [OLED](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108588/8627/)(4) [OP-AMP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108651/8627/)(8) [OTA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108741/8627/)(3)

**`P` -** [P-P](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109837/8627/)(0) [PAL (logic)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108650/8627/)(2) [PAL (television)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109236/8627/)(0) [PC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109835/8627/)(-1) [PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108544/8627/)(17) [PCBA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108547/8627/)(-5) [PCM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108589/8627/)(4) [PFM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109323/8627/)(-2) [PIC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109798/8627/)(0) [PID](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108593/8627/)(9) [PLL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108558/8627/)(9) [PM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108831/8627/)(0) , [*duplicate*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109884/8627/)(0) [PNP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108526/8627/)(14) [POR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109324/8627/)(3) [PPM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109796/8627/)(-1) [PSK](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108830/8627/)(5) [PUT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108647/8627/)(-1) [PWM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108549/8627/)(24)

**`Q` -** [QM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108859/8627/)(-6) [QVGA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109843/8627/)(0)

**`R` -** [RADAR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109872/8627/)(0) [RAM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108564/8627/)(12) [RF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108841/8627/)(5) [RFID](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108594/8627/)(6) [RGB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108595/8627/)(4) [RJ45](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108590/8627/)(6) [ROM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109834/8627/)(3) [RTL (discrete logic)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109235/8627/)(2) [RTL (Verilog)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108560/8627/)(2)

**`S` -** [SAW](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108645/8627/)(3) [SCR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108570/8627/)(9) [SD,SDHC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109857/8627/)(0) [SDCC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109062/8627/)(-3) [SMA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108622/8627/)(4) [SMPS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108556/8627/)(9) [SMT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108583/8627/)(5) [SNR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108596/8627/)(5) [SOC/SoC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108605/8627/)(5) [SPI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108540/8627/)(13) [SPICE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108673/8627/)(8) [SRAM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108562/8627/)(6) [SRPP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109833/8627/)(-2) [STA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108601/8627/)(0)

**`T` -** [TBH](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108652/8627/)(-8) [TCXO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108865/8627/)(2) [THD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108658/8627/)(6) [TRF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109868/8627/)(-1) [TTL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108598/8627/)(10) [TVS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108554/8627/)(4)

**`U` -** [UART](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108528/8627/)(12) [UHF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108837/8627/)(4) [UJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108648/8627/)(0) [UL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108613/8627/)(3) [USART](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108649/8627/)(4) [USB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108599/8627/)(4)

**`V` -** [V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108817/8627/)(2) [VCA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108827/8627/)(1) [VCC / VEE / VDD / VSS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108644/8627/)(14) [VCCS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108743/8627/)(1) [VCO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108852/8627/)(5) [VCXO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108996/8627/)(3) [VFD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108557/8627/)(3) [VGA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108600/8627/)(-2) [VHDL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108602/8627/)(7) [VHF](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108835/8627/)(5) [VLSI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109855/8627/)(2) [VNL,VFL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109860/8627/)(-1) [VSWR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108858/8627/)(4)

**`W` -** [W](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108822/8627/)(2)

**`X` -** [XO](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108856/8627/)(1) [XOR](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/109836/8627/)(3) [XTAL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108862/8627/)(5)

**`Ω` -** [Ω](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108711/8627/)(0)

<sub>186 answers - Sun May 11 09:17:28 2014 (CET)</sub>

Comment: [IEEE's take on the subject](http://www.ewh.ieee.org/soc/ias/pub-dept/abbreviation.pdf)

Comment: The links don’t seem to work. Not on iPhones anyway.

Answer (score 31):

## PWM

Pulse Width Modulation. A method of controlling duty cycle by chopping as opposed to [throttling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throttle).

Answer (score 25):

### LED

Light Emitting Diode.

Blinking an LED is considered the "Hello world" of a circuit design, and it can be as simple as putting a series resistor or can get more complicated, involving [PWM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108549/5599) and multiplexing.

Tag: [led](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/led)

Answer (score 22):

## LCD

Liquid-Crystal Display, used to display characters or graphics

Answer (score 21):

## CMOS

Complementary Metal Oxide Semiconductor.

Answer (score 21):

## FET

Field Effect Transistor.  There are various sub-types of this, like [JFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108553/5599) (PN junction separates gate and body) and [MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108541/5599) (metal oxide insulated gate).

Answer (score 20):

## MOSFET

Metal Oxide Semiconductor Field Effect Transistor.  See also [FET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108527/5599).

Answer (score 20):

## DAC

or

## D/A

Digital-to-Analog Converter

Answer (score 19):

## PCB

Printed circuit board.  A board made typically made out of a fiberglass reinforced epoxy (FR4), which has traces on at least one side and is used to mount electronic components.

Originally, PCBs had just through-hole components on one side, and thus the top was called the component side, and the bottom the solder side (where the traces were).

Now a PCB will often have traces and surface mount components on both sides, and may in addition have interior layers (in even numbers, so the total layers are 2, 4, 6, 8 etc.).  These interior layers are used for additional traces or power planes.

Answer (score 19):

## ADC

or

## A/D

Analog-to-Digital Converter

Answer (score 18):

## BJT

Bipolar Junction Transistor.  See [NPN](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108524/5599) and [PNP](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108526/5599).

The first transistors developed were of this type.  After other types appeared (such as field effect transistors), the name BJT was chosen to differentiate these from the others.

Answer (score 18):

## GND

Ground reference. The node in a circuit that is 0V by definition.

Comment: But note that this can't always stand alone (and the definition is a little misleading when it suggests there is only one ground node/reference in any circuit).  For example, electrical equipment may have "earth ground", "chassis ground", "analog ground", "digital ground", and one or more "isolated ground" nodes, often associated with external connections.

Comment: Side note: it's not that the reference node is _defined_ to be at a voltage of 0 V. Instead, it has a voltage of 0 V because it is measured with respect to itself.

Answer (score 16):

## PNP

Positive-Negative-Positive.  One of the two types of bipolar junction transistors ([BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108529/5599)). Here positive and negative refer to positively and negatively doped semiconductor regions.

Answer (score 16):

## DSP

Digital Signal Processing/Processor

Answer (score 15):

## SPI

Serial peripheral interface. A single master, multiple slave communication protocol.  Clock rates can go into the 10's of MHz.

It comprises the following lines:

```
SCK - clock
MOSI - master out slave in (typically data from microcontroller to IC)
MISO - master in slave (typically data from IC back to microcontroller)
SS - slave select.  One SS is required for each IC on the same bus.
```

Answer (score 15):

## I²C

(also I2C or IIC).  Inter-integrated circuit.  A single master, multiple slave communication protocol using a 2-wire serial bus (SCL - serial clock line and SDA - serial data line).  Used to connect [IC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108582)'s on a [PCB](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108544/5599), and less often, IC's on different PCBs.  Typical clock rates are 100 k and 400 k baud.

Unlike [SPI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108540/5599), slave select lines are not required as each chip has a unique address.

Comment: Sometimes this is also referred to as TWI (Two Wire Interface)

Comment: @hassansin I believe Atmel didn't want to pay the I²C license fee (to either Philips or NXP), so they came up with their own name. Not sure if the TWI spec is different in details or not.

Comment: It is also referred to as IIC.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, I added that.

Answer (score 15):

## EEPROM

Electrically Erasable Programmable Read-Only Memory, a type of non-volatile memory. Also sometimes referred to as E2PROM.

Answer (score 15):

## V<sub>CC</sub> / V<sub>EE</sub> / V<sub>DD</sub> / V<sub>SS</sub>

**V<sub>CC</sub>**: Positive power rail voltage (usually in [BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108529) technology)

**V<sub>EE</sub>**: Negative power rail voltage (usually in BJT technology)

**V<sub>DD</sub>**: Positive power rail voltage (usually in [FET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108527) technology)

**V<sub>SS</sub>**: Negative power rail voltage (usually in FET technology)

[What is the difference between \$V_{CC}\$, \$V_{DD}\$, \$V_{EE}\$, \$V_{SS}\$](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17382/what-is-the-difference-between-vcc-vdd-vee-vss)

Comment: Although these are related, I believe they mentioned one term per definition.

Comment: @JFA By all means, do feel free to add three answers but do cross-reference them.

Comment: How about this?

**Vpp:** programming/erase voltage (usually in PIC microcontrollers)

Comment: @Kamil Good one, but I think it deserves its own entry because it has little to do with power supply rails.

Answer (score 14):

## UART

Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter.  A UART implements the common "serial" protocol, such as used by RS-232 and PC COM ports.

Data is sent on a single signal.  Each word (typically a 8-bit byte) is sent by a start bit, followed by the data bits, followed by a stop bit.  The bit timing must be agreed on by both ends ahead of time.  The receiver uses the leading edge of the start bit as the time reference for the remaining bits in that word.  The stop bit is at the line idle level, and guarantees that the there will be a transition at the leading edge of the next start bit.

Comment: [USART/UART](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108649/11123) also exists, and includes both types.

Answer (score 13):

## ASCII

American Standard Code for Information Interchange

Answer (score 12):

## RAM

Random-access memory, a misnomer that usually refers to any volatile semiconductor memory. The term *random access* was originally used to differentiate memory technology that required sequential access to stored data (i.e. delay-line memory, rotating disks, magnetic and paper tape) from those memory technologies that would allow you to access any sequence of locations, in any order, without penalty. Strictly speaking, flash memory is a random-access memory but it is never categorized as RAM.

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate on why it is a misnomer.

Answer (score 11):

## NPN

Negative-Positive-Negative, indicating the type of doping of each region.  One of the two types of bipolar junction transistors ([BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108529/5599)).

Comment: it stands for n-doped, p-doped, n-doped. or n-type, p-type, n-type.

Answer (score 11):

## ESD

Electrostatic discharge. "Static electricity." Particularly dangerous to [CMOS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108523/5599) parts.  Sometimes used to refer to the process of dealing with static discharge susceptibility in design.

Answer (score 11):

## GPIO

General Purpose Input / Output

This is usually used to refer to a pin of a microcontroller that can be either input or output under firmware control.  It can also refer to a externally available signal of a circuit board or whole device that is intended to produce or receive a digital signal, depending on configuration or other usage.

Answer (score 11):

## JFET

Junction field effect transistor. A type of [FET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108527/5599).

This is the original FET.  After the development of the [MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108541/5599), the Junction designation was added to distinguish it from other types.

Answer (score 11):

## IC

Integrated circuit, a semicondutor device incorporating several circuit elements

Answer (score 10):

## SMPS

Switch-mode power supply (or switch-mode power supply unit) - can be generally applied to any or combinations of the following: -

- Buck converter
- Boost converter
- Fly-back converter
- SEPIC converter (single-ended primary-inductor converter)
- [list not exhaustive]

Answer (score 10):

## PLL

[Phase-Locked Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop). Used for frequency synthesis and FM demodulation.

Answer (score 10):

## CAN

Controller area network, a message-based serial protocol with differential signaling.

[tag wiki](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/can/info) for [can](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/can)

Answer (score 10):

## SCR

Silicon Controlled Rectifier.

SCRs are unidirectional devices triggered only by currents going into the gate.

Comment: Once triggered, they continue to conduct until the load current is removed.  They are also called "thyristors".

Answer (score 10):

## FPGA

[Field-Programmable Gate Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) A type of programmable logic device that uses LUTs (Look Up Table) to implement complex logic.

Answer (score 10):

## TTL

Transistor-Transistor Logic

Answer (score 10):

## OP-AMP

also

## OpAmp

Operational Amplifier.

An amplifier with very high gain and differential inputs. That is, for a conventional op-amp, the output voltage is a large multiple of the difference between the voltage at the two inputs.

Comment: These abbreviations should be separate. I don't think **OA** is as good or recognized an abbreviation, at least not without context.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing OA, since OP-AMP is the more common abbreviation.

Comment: I also see/use **OPA** a lot. Without making an implication of TI parts.

Answer (score 10):

## CPU

Short for Central Processing Unit.

Answer (score 9):

## PID

Proportional, Integral, Derivative. A type of controller used in control systems.

Answer (score 9):

## VHDL

VHSIC Hardware Description Language

where VHSIC is Very High Speed Integrated Circuit

Answer (score 9):

## SPICE

Simulation Program with Integrated Circuit Emphasis

Answer (score 9):

## IGBT

Insulated Gate Bipolar transistor.  A device that combines the high impedance input characteristics of a MOSFET with the high current output capabilities of a BJT.

Answer (score 9):

## DC

Direct current is the unidirectional flow of electric charge.

Comment: The equivalent for voltage waveforms is **not DV**, but rather **DC voltage**.

Answer (score 9):

## AC

Alternating current is the flow of electric charge that periodically reverses direction.

Comment: The equivalent for voltage waveforms is **not AV**, but rather **AC voltage**.

Answer (score 8):

## FIFO/LIFO

FIFO: First-In, First-Out (a queue)

LIFO: Last-In, First-Out (a stack)

Answer (score 8):

## ASIC

Application-Specific Integrated Circuit

Answer (score 8):

## JTAG

Joint Test Action Group

also used to describe the serial interface defined by this group

Answer (score 8):

## AWG

American Wire Gauge, a wire gauge standard widely used in North America.

Answer (score 8):

## BNC

Bayonet Neill–Concelman connector; a miniture quick-connect/disconnect RF coaxial connector

Answer (score 8):

## FM

Short for "Frequency Modulation"

Answer (score 8):

## FFT

An algorithm that rapidly computes the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of a periodic signal. FFT is very commonly used to mean the DFT, the output of the FFT algorithm.

See also: DFT, DTFT/CTFT, IFT

Answer (score 8):

## MUX

A multiplexer is a device that selects one of several analog or digital input signals and forwards the selected input into a single line.

Answer (score 7):

### EDA

Electronic Design Automation. A set of tools made to design electronic circuits. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_EDA_software)

Answer (score 7):

## DMA

Direct-Memory Access, used for high-throughput interfaces in digital systems

Comment: DMA and bus-mastering aren't restricted to high-throughput interfaces.

Answer (score 7):

## SRAM

Static Random Access Memory

Answer (score 7):

### RJ45

Registered Jack 45. A famous one of the long list of registered jacks since it is used for most ethernets.  It has 8 pins, connected to four twisted pair in common ethernet wiring.

Answer (score 7):

## RFID

Radio Frequency Identification

Answer (score 7):

## SNR

Signal-to-Noise       Ratio

Answer (score 7):

## USB

Universal    Serial    Bus

Answer (score 7):

## MCU

microcontroller. a small computer on a IC.

**Notice**: a small computer Not a processor. then it containing a processor core, memory, and programmable input/output peripherals

Comment: Should be only ***one*** abbreviation per answer.

Comment: Should I modify this answer and separate it to three answer?

Comment: Yes, so they can be voted on individually.

Comment: @JYelton ok. thanks

Answer (score 7):

## LVDS

Low voltage differential signalling -- commonly used for high-speed digital communications and lcd display interfaces

Answer (score 7):

## THD

Total Harmonic Distortion, which is a measure of how much noise is introduced as a result of non-linear processes.

Answer (score 7):

## EE

- Electronics Engineer(ing)
- Electrical Engineer(ing)

Comment: Also, Electrical Engineer.

Comment: Sometimes "double E" when spoken, but that is not common outside of our engineering community.

Answer (score 7):

## AM

Short for "Amplitude Modulation"

Answer (score 6):

## CCD

Charge-Coupled Device, used to describe some imaging devices

Comment: Most often used in imaging today, but can also refer more generally to a type of logic or memory.

Answer (score 6):

## MEMS

Micro ElectroMechanical Systems.

MEMS are devices that can fit into small sized packages, typically up to few millimeters wide, and implement electro-mechanical functions such as sensing or actuating.

Answer (score 6):

## DIP

Dual-Inline Package, an integrated packaging style for through-hole assembly

Comment: Also known as 'DIL'

Answer (score 6):

## BCD

[Binary Coded Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

The act or process of encoding decimal in a binary format, usually 0000 to 1001.

Answer (score 6):

## KCL, KVL

Kirchhoff's laws

[Kirchhoff's Current Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws): 
The sum of currents flowing into a node is zero.
In come countries this is referred to as 1st  Kirchhoff's law.

[Kirchhoff's Voltage Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws): The sum of voltages around a loop is zero.
In come countries this is referred to as 2nd  Kirchhoff's law.

Answer (score 6):

### XTAL

Piezoelectric crystal (quartz)

Answer (score 6):

## XOR

exclusive-or

Boolean logic function. Returns true if any input is different from another input.

Answer (score 5):

## CAD

Computer-Aided Design (as in CAD/CAM)

Comment: This one's been repurposed from "Computer-Aided Drafting"

Answer (score 5):

## TVS

[Transient Voltage Suppression diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_voltage_suppression_diode)

Answer (score 5):

## GPS

Global Positioning System

but not Global Positioning *Satellite*

Comment: Mmm this is kind of obvious, I'm not sure it's worth having it

Answer (score 5):

## SMT

Surface mount technologies. Also written as **SMD**, for surface mount devices.

Components that are soldered directly to pads of exposed copper on circuit boards, instead of the traditional through hole, or wire wrapped construction methods.

Answer (score 5):

## OLED

organic light-emitting diode

Answer (score 5):

## SOC/SoC

System   On     a     Chip

Answer (score 5):

## SMA

SubMiniture version A - a subminiture RF coaxial connector

Answer (score 5):

## ISP

In System Programming, also referred to as **ICSP** --  In Circuit System Programming

Answer (score 5):

## USART

Universal Synchronous/Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter.  Usually used to describe a microcontroller peripheral that can be configured to be used as a [UART](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108528/4512), but also to implement one or more synchronous serial protocols (like [SPI](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108540/4512) and [I<sup>2</sup>C](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108550/4512), for example).

Answer (score 5):

## GBW

Gain Bandwidth Product. The product of an amplifier's gain and its open loop bandwidth is commonly considered constant. When an amplifier is configured for high gain, the bandwidth will be reduced and the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

## DVM/DMM

Digital Volt Meter / Digital Multimeter; A DVM measures only voltage, while a DMM includes (at least) current and resistance. May be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 5):

## LUT

Look Up Table: a component in [FPGA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108575), or a part of software program.

Answer (score 5):

## BLDC

Brushless Direct Current (DC) Motor

Comment: I personally don't care for this abbreviation, but I see it often.

Answer (score 5):

## PSK

Phase Shift Keying. Simple modulation method used for digital communications

Answer (score 5):

## VHF

Very High Frequency radio (30 MHz ~ 300 MHz).  Today the terms "low", "medium", "high", etc, are not very meaningful relative to the radio spectrum in common use.  However, these terms have evolved somewhat standard meanings from historical context, so now are just used to refer to certain radio bands.  See other terms like ELF, VLF, LF, HF, UHF, etc.

Answer (score 5):

## RF

Short for Radio frequency. [(3 kHz ~ 300 GHz)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency)

Answer (score 5):

## VCO

Voltage Controlled Oscillator. An oscillator which its frequency can be controlled with an input voltage.

Answer (score 4):

### EMC

ElectroMagnetic Compatibility. It's the discipline of electrical engineering concerned with controlling the electromagnetic radiation generated by electronic devices and the amount of such radiation that the devices can withstand/tolerate. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_compatibility)

Answer (score 4):

## FSM

Finite State Machine, can be either Mealy or Moore style

Answer (score 4):

## MIDI

Musical Instrument Digital Interface.

A standard for digital communication between electronic musical instruments, specifying both a protocol and hardware standards. MIDI data is usually transmitted over USB, or as a balanced serial data stream at 31.25kbps, using three conductors (+5V, signal, ground) and cables terminated in 5-pin 180° DIN plugs.

Answer (score 4):

## PCM

pulse-code      modulation

Answer (score 4):

## DRC

Design Rule Checking or Check(s)

Answer (score 4):

## RGB

Red Green Blue, an additive color model

Answer (score 4):

## CPLD

complex programmable logic device

Answer (score 4):

## ECL

Emitter coupled logic, a fast BJT logic family.
Also related: **NECL** -- negative emitter coupled logic and **PECL** -- positive emitter coupled logic

Answer (score 4):

### Hz

Hertz - one cycle per second

### kHz

Kilohertz - one thousand (10<sup>3</sup>) cycles per second

### MHz

Megahertz - one million (10<sup>6</sup>) cycles per second

### GHz

Gigahertz - one billion (10<sup>9</sup>) cycles per second

### THz

Terahertz - one trillion (10<sup>12</sup>) cycles per second

Comment: Should be only one abbreviation per answer. I think the units are useful but the metric prefixes are not necessary

Comment: @Gorloth I disagree.  Firwt of all, I'm trying to show commonly used prefixes (e.g. millihertz is not used).  Secondly, this allows just one entry in the index for H (Hertz), and a user can come to this entry to see all the variations.  Otherwise you are going to glog the index with all the prefixes (which I think are important).  Note this has gotten quite a few votes in its present form.

Comment: If you want commonly used values it seems like it would be sufficient to mention that in the description (Hz - hertz a unit of cycles per second, commonly used in kHz to Thz ranges) seems that metric prefixes are not really EE specific, maybe an edit to make the unit vs prefix distinction more  clear, not sure how to best do that though

Answer (score 4):

## UHF

Short for Ultra High Frequency (300 MHz ~ 3 GHz)

Answer (score 4):

## HF

Short for "High Frequency".

Answer (score 4):

## LPF

Short for "Low Pass Filter". Frequencies above the cut off frequency are attenuated.

Comment: I have never heard this abbreviated like this, it would be nice to have someone weigh in as this is important in EE

Answer (score 4):

## IF

Intermediate Frequency. Commonly used in [Superheterodyne Receivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superheterodyne_receiver), where the tuned radio frequency is mixed down to a fixed intermediate frequency, where in turn the signal is demodulated to the audio band. Eg. for PAL TV 38.9MHz.

Answer (score 4):

## VSWR

Voltage [Standing Wave Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave_ratio). In RF technology when a transmission line is not properly terminated, the voltage along the line will vary.

Answer (score 4):

### VCXO

Voltage-Controlled Crystal Oscillator. A crystal oscillator that can be "pulled" away from its nominal frequency by means of an analog control voltage.

Answer (score 4):

## ALU

Arithmetic and Logic Unit. The arithmetic and logic brain in a microprocessor.

Answer (score 4):

## EPROM

Erasable Programmable Read-Only Memory. Non-volatile memory which preserves it contents even without a power supply. It may be erased by applying ultraviolet light onto the die. EPROM memories have been mostly replaced by EEPROM memories.

Answer (score 4):

## ROM

[Read-only memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory)

Data persists after power is removed.

Answer (score 3):

## VFD

Variable-frequency drive, a type of adjustable-speed AC motor drive

OR

Vacuum fluorescent display, a high-intensity segment display technology

Comment: Is that the same as VLT? [VLT is a registered trademark from Danfoss.](http://www.danfoss.com/BusinessAreas/DrivesSolutions/)

Answer (score 3):

## UL

Underwriters Laboratories, a company that certifies the safety of a wide variety of electrical products

Answer (score 3):

## SAW

Surface Acoustic Wave filter

Answer (score 3):

## LF

Short for Low Frequency, often audio spectrum (0 - 20kHz)

Answer (score 3):

## HPF

Short for "High Pass Filter". A High Pass filter attenuates frequencies below the cut off frequency.

Answer (score 3):

## DFT

The Discrete Fourier Transform. A ordered sequence of numbers that represent the energy and phase of a discrete, periodic signal at some frequency (the frequency represented by the n-th term depends on how fast or 'close together' your input samples are; see other references).

For a discrete signal with period N, ${x_0,...,x_{N-1}}$, the DFT will be of length N, and the DFT at each $k$ from 1 to N is:

$$\tilde{X}(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)\cdot e^{-i2\pi k n/N}$$

Not to be confused with the DTFT!

See also: DTFT/CTFT, IFT, FFT

Answer (score 3):

## h<sub>FE</sub>

The large-signal current gain of a [BJT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108529) transistor.  Defined as I<sub>C</sub>/I<sub>B</sub> in the forward-active mode.

Comment: I rather think, this parameter hFE is defined as the SMALL-SIGNAL forward current gain in common emitter configuration.

Comment: Can you provide a definition for Ic and Ib also in this summary?

Answer (score 3):

## ASK

Amplitude Shift Keying.

Simple modulation method used for digital communications in which digital data is represented as variations in amplitude of carrier wave.

Answer (score 3):

## FSK

Frequency Shift Keying.

Simple modulation method used for digital communications in which digital data is represented as variations in frequency of carrier wave.

Answer (score 3):

## DSO

Digital Storage Oscilloscope.

Electronic testing/measuring instrument which can store and analyze the signal digitally. DSO use LCD display to show the signals.

Answer (score 3):

## LSB, MSB

Least Significant Bit.

Most Significant Bit.

Answer (score 3):

## VLSI

Very Large Scale Integration

Answer (score 3):

## QFP

Quad Flat Package

(A surface mount IC package)

Answer (score 3):

## ARM

Advanced RISC Machine.

(Architecture for computer processors)

Answer (score 3):

## RISC, CISC

RISC - Reduced Instruction set computing.

CISC - Complex Instruction set computing.

Answer (score 3):

## EMI

Electromagnetic Interference. Undesirable and possibly problematic signal emitted by an electronic device. Emission of EMI is often restricted by organizations such as the United State's Federal Communications Commission.

Answer (score 2):

## RTL (Verilog)

Register-Transfer Level. A subset of the Verilog / [VHDL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108602/5599) language that is synthesisable.

Comment: Also Resistor-Transistor Logic, mostly obsoleted by TTL.

Comment: Check again. It's not 'Resistor' or 'Transistor' or 'logic'

Comment: I checked. Sometimes it is. http://doctord.dyndns.org/courses/Topics/Digital_Logic/digital/electronics/rtl_gates.html Your move.

Comment: Huh, that's not what RTL is used for!!

Comment: Well it's true you won't see the original RTL very often nowadays.

Comment: @BrianDrummond is correct; RTL also stands for "Resistor Transistor Logic". There are also DTL, IIL, and a plethora of other digital logic families that didn't make it big.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I created a separate RTL (logic) entry.

Answer (score 2):

## PAL (logic)

[Programmable Array Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_Array_Logic). Sometimes also sold under GAL.

Answer (score 2):

## BW

"BW" is short for Bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

## OTA

[Operational transconductance amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transconductance_amplifier) Similar to an opamp, but an output current instead of an output voltage. Effectively a voltage controlled current source.

Answer (score 2):

### A

SI symbol for [ampere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere) - measure of the amount of electric charge passing a point in an electric circuit per unit time, abbreviated as:

### mA

Milliampere - one thousandth (10<sup>-3</sup>) of an ampere

### µA

Microampere - one millionth (10<sup>-6</sup>) of an ampere

### nA

Nanoampere - 10<sup>-9</sup> ampere

Comment: I don't understand why such standard, common abbreviations as these would be down-voted.

Answer (score 2):

### F

SI symbol for farad (measure of capacitance), abbreviated as:

### mF

Millifarad - one thousandth (10<sup>-3</sup>) of a farad

### µF

Microfarad - one millionth (10<sup>-6</sup>) of a farad

### nF

Nanofarad - 10<sup>-9</sup> farad

### pF

Picofarad - 10<sup>-12</sup> farad

Comment: -1.  I'm downvoting all the unit posts.  Do we have a goal to go all the way to the First Principles?  I think, it's safe to expect the posters to be familiar with the SI system.

Comment: I agree that units probably shouldn't even be on this list, but at the same time, the down-votes make them look as though they are "unacceptable." I think they should at least have a positive score or be omitted from this list.

Comment: @NickAlexeev The title of the original question is "What are abbreviations used in electrical engineering?".  How do these not fit that criteria?  A newbie, running across the term pF, probably doesn't know what that is.  It's more likely they have only seen µF in schematics.

Answer (score 2):

### H

SI symbol for henry (measure of inductance), abbreviated as:

### mH

Millihenry - one thousandth (10<sup>-3</sup>) of a henry

### µH

Microhenry - one millionth (10<sup>-6</sup>) of a henry

### nH

Nanohenry - 10<sup>-9</sup> henry

Answer (score 2):

### W

Symbol for [watt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watt) - measure of power (joules per second), abbreviated as:

### mW

Milliwatt - one thousandth (10<sup>-3</sup>) of a watt

### µW

Microwatt - one millionth (10<sup>-6</sup>) of a watt

### kW

Kilowatt - one thousand (10<sup>3</sup>) watts

### MW

Megawatt - one million (10<sup>6</sup>) watts

### GW

Gigawatt - 10<sup>9</sup> watt

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales

Comment: @jippie -- I am using the short scales, each new term is 1000 times (or 1/1000 times) the previous. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigawatt#Multiples

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but I thought 10^9 was commonly called billion. Whether it is the one or the other isn't really the point I wanted to make, my point is that it may be unclear for some. Other than that it is probably a detail we shouldn't worry too much about.

Comment: @jippie Thx, that was a typo (cut and paste from another answer).

Answer (score 2):

## OCXO

Oven Controlled Crystal Oscillator. Although a crystal oscillator is already pretty stable by itself, it does however vary its frequency with temperature. By keeping the crystal in a small oven and warming it to a given and stable temperature, the output frequency is no longer influenced by external temperature variations.

Answer (score 2):

## TCXO

Temperature Compensated Crystal Oscillator. Although a crystal oscillator is already pretty stable by itself, it does however vary its frequency with temperature. By measuring the temperature and adjusting other parameter(s) of the oscillator circuit to compensate, the output frequency is less influenced by external temperature variations.

Answer (score 2):

## DEMUX

or

## DMX

A demultiplexer is a device taking a single input signal and selecting one of many data-output-lines, which is connected to the single input.

Comment: DMX is likely to be confused with a stage lighting automation standard.

Answer (score 2):

## RTL (discrete logic)

[Resistor-Transistor Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic), mostly obsoleted by TTL. There are also DTL, IIL, and a plethora of other digital logic families that didn't make it big

Answer (score 2):

## FFC

Flexible Flat Cable. (Or sometimes Flat Flexible Cable.) Usually refers to the thin, flat, high signal-density cables used for board-to-board or board-to-wire communication. They are commonly used on display modules and often have small pitch.

The board-to-wire connectors used to connect the cables are referred to as *FFC connectors*.

Answer (score 2):

## I<sup>2</sup>S

Inter-IC sound. (sometimes reffed to as IIS). electrical serial bus used for connecting digital audio devices together. The I<sup>2</sup>S bus separates clock and serial data signals, it is the most common form of PCM audio data transmission in modern consumer electronics.

Answer (score 2):

## POR

Power-on Reset. A microcontroller featuring a POR (the majority, if not all, modern micros) detects when the power is rising from below the operation threshold, and once it hits a sufficient level to operate stably, triggers a chip-wide reset that fully initializes all peripherals and registers to the specified initial state.

Answer (score 2):

## SD,SDHC

Secure digital, Secure Digital High Capacity

Answer (score 2):

## CMRR

Common Mode Rejection Ratio. Defined for an op-amp as:
$$
CMRR = \frac{Diff\ mode\ gain}{Common\ mode\ gain }
$$

Comment: I believe a better definition of CMRR for opamps is \$\frac{\Delta V_{OS}}{V_{ICM}}\$. I.e. The change in **input offset voltage** vs. change in **input common mode voltage**. CMRR is also relevant for matched bridges and for common-mode filters.

Answer (score 1):

## STA

Static Timing Analysis: A method for verifying timing in digital design.

Comment: May I know why down-voted?

Comment: Probably was somebody that doesn't know jack about digital design, I'll compensate when the vote counter resets.

Comment: It's a correct acronym, but I'd argue something that should be spelled out if used on this site.

Answer (score 1):

## CCCS

Current Controlled Current Source

Answer (score 1):

### ms

Millisecond - one thousandth (10<sup>-3</sup>) of a second

### µs

Microsecond - one millionth (10<sup>-6</sup>) of a second

### ns

Nanosecond - one billionth (10<sup>-9</sup>) of a second

### ps

Picosecond - one trillionth (10<sup>-12</sup>) of a second

Answer (score 1):

## VCCS

Voltage Controlled Current Source

Answer (score 1):

## VCA

Voltage Controlled Amplifier

Answer (score 1):

## DLL

Short for "[Delay Locked Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay-locked_loop)".

Answer (score 1):

## BPF

Short for Band Pass Filter. A Band Pass Filter attenuates frequencies outside its pass-band, it attenuates frequencies below its lower cut off frequency and above its higher cut off frequency.

Answer (score 1):

## QM

Quine-McCluskey, an algorithm for minimizing two level logic.

Answer (score 1):

## IFT

The Inverse Fourier Transform (IFT) is used in general to mean the action of taking frequency-and-phase data (be it a finite set of values, as in the DFT, or a function on continuous space as in the DTFT or CTFT), and turning it into time-domain data. (or spatial domain, etc., depending on context)

Answer (score 1):

## PAL (television)

[Phase Alternating Line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAL), a colour encoding system for analogue television, mainly used in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

## NTSC

National Television System Committee, but generally refers to their specification for OTA TV broadcasting.  The video signal requires 6 MHz of bandwidth and is broadcast at 29.97 fps with 525 interlaced lines, of which only 483 are visible.

Answer (score 1):

## RADAR

RAdio Detection And Ranging

Answer (score 1):

## TFT

Thin Film Transistor.

(A special kind of FET used in LCD.)

Answer (score 1):

**QAM**

Quadrature amplitude modulation.

A digital (or analog) modulation scheme where the amplitudes of two orthogonal carrier waves (in-phase and quadrature) are modulated.

Answer (score 1):

## DDR

Double data rate.

(As in DDR RAM)

Answer (score 1):

## IEEE

Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers.

Answer (score 1):

## BLE

Bluetooth Low Energy. Newest Bluetooth technology using Bluetooth 4.0 and has a range of 50m instead of 10.

(Only android 4.3 devices with BLE support can use BLE and apple products newer than the iPhone 4G).

Answer (score 1):

## HDMI

High-Definition Multimedia Interface. A compact audio/video interface for transferring uncompressed video data and compressed or uncompressed digital audio data from a HDMI-compliant source device to a compatible computer monitor, video projector, digital television, or digital audio device.

Answer (score 1):

## ISA

[Instruction Set Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) is an abstraction of a processing unit. It defines the instructions, register and memory to execute the program line by line. It can be implemented on FPGA or ASIC to become a processing unit.

For example, [RISC-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC-V) is an open-source ISA.

Answer (score 0):

## PCBA

Printed Circuit Board Assembly; a PCB (Printed Circuit Board) with components fitted and ready for use.

Comment: PCBA. Never heard the acronym PCA.

Comment: We use PCA at my work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

## DVD

Digital Video Disc or Digital Versatile Disc

Answer (score 0):

## NVM

Non Volatile Memory such as fuse or flash based, retains data after power loss.

Comment: more common: NVRAM

Comment: @BenVoigt Wikipedia would beg to differ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_memory. And as a user of NVM for many years I've never even heard of NVRAM.

Comment: wikipedia is not making any claims about how often an abbreviation is used.  Compare https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=NVM%2CNVRAM&year_start=1990&year_end=2008

Comment: Wikipedia knows NVRAM as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_random-access_memory  Part of the reason that NVRAM is a more useful abbreviation than NVM, is that whether memory is random-access is a very important characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

## HDTV

High-Definition Television

Answer (score 0):

## VGA

Video   Graphics   Adapter

Comment: [Video Graphics ***Array***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) technically. :)

Comment: And while it originally referred to a particular display adapter board for a PC, it now refers generically to the video *interface* it defined: 15-pin high-density D-sub connector, discrete analog RGB signals, TTL sync signals, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## LVDT

Linear Variable Differential Transformer

Answer (score 0):

## PUT

Programmable Unijunction Transistor

Answer (score 0):

## UJT

Unijunction Transistor.  A relatively obscure type of transistor not used much today (2014).

Answer (score 0):

## TBH

Take Back Half. An alternative for a [PID](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108593) control loop.

http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4325740/Temperature-controller-has-take-back-half-convergence-algorithm

Answer (score 0):

## CC

"CC" is short for Constant Current.

Comment: Ambiguous, should be spelled out.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sometimes you can't help what's printed on the front of your bench-top power supply.

Comment: I agree with Jonathon, I have two such different supplies on my desk, different brands, both are using the abbreviations "CC" and "CV".

Answer (score 0):

## EOS

Electrical Over Stress: Damage to a device due to a current or voltage that is beyond the specification limits of the device

Comment: EOS is the proper terminology and not ESD control.

Answer (score 0):

## LVS

Layout Versus Schematic: A method for verifying the functionality of a layout with the schematic/netlist of the design.

Comment: DRC is voted up, LVS is voted down!!

Answer (score 0):

## IGFET

Insulated Gate Field Effect Transistor.

This is a less commonly used name for a [MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108541).   But the "insulated gate" terminolgy *is* used for the IGBT.

Answer (score 0):

### Ω

SI symbol for ohm, abbreviated as:

### kΩ

Kilohm - one thousand (10<sup>3</sup>) ohms

### MΩ

Megohm - one million (10<sup>6</sup>) ohms

### GΩ

Gigaohm - (10<sup>9</sup>) ohm

Comment: @jippie removed

Comment: This is a unit not abbreviation. -1 because I think it should be removed.

Comment: @Kamil Yes, I agree Ω is a unit.  kΩ is an abbreviation, otherwise it would be written as kilohm all the time (and k by itself, as in 100k with the ohms implied, is certainly an abbreviation).  I deleted the initial entry for Ω and just left the other three entries, **which are abbreviations**.

Comment: So shall we add all this for SI units? Volts, amperes, watts, henries, farads... ?

Comment: @Kamil Yes, actually I have already, along with their abbreviations.  I agree that for example H is an SI symbol, **but mH for example is an abbreviation**, which is what this question is all about.

Answer (score 0):

## HVSP

High Voltage Serial Programmer. Programming mode used to program (Atmel AVR) devices that have been fuse protected for reading / writing. It uses 12 V at a certain pin, hence "high" voltage.

Answer (score 0):

## I/P

This is short for "input".

Comment: The very reason for starting the question ;o)

Comment: In electronics, IP most often stands for Internet Protocol suite or IP number. Less often as Intellectual Property or some such, used for CPU or SoC blocks. I've never seen it used for "input" though.

Answer (score 0):

## O/P

This is short for "output".

Comment: The very reason for starting the question ;o)

Answer (score 0):

### V

SI symbol for [volt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt) - measure of electric potential, abbreviated as:

### mV

Millivolt - one thousandth (10<sup>-3</sup>) of a volt

### µV

Microvolt - one millionth (10<sup>-6</sup>) of a volt

### nV

Nanovolt - one bilionth (10<sup>-9</sup>) of a volt

### kV

Kilovolt - one thousand (10<sup>3</sup>) volts

### MV

Megavolt - one million (10<sup>6</sup>) volts

### GV

Gigavolt - one billion (10<sup>9</sup>) volts

Comment: I think that putting the SI units goes too far from the scope of this post.

Comment: Especially since kV, and nV are in common usage as well, the attempt other definitions with units are making to show the common ranges completely fails here.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree about kV and added it to my anser I've never actually seen nV, and it doesn't even show up on a Google search so I'm leaving that one out.

Comment: @tcrosley: Check the noise density for your favorite low-noise opamp, the datasheet will list it in $$nV / \sqrt{Hz}$$

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

## XO

"XO" is short for "Crystal Oscillator".

Answer (score 0):

### NEXT

Near End Crosstalk, a concept in full-duplex communication links.

Answer (score 0):

## SDCC

SDCC - Small Device C Compiler

[SDCC is a retargettable, optimizing ANSI - C compiler suite that targets the Intel MCS51 based microprocessors (8031, 8032, 8051, 8052, etc.), Maxim (formerly Dallas) DS80C390 variants, Freescale (formerly Motorola) HC08 based (hc08, s08), Zilog Z80 based MCUs (z80, z180, gbz80, Rabbit 2000/3000, Rabbit 3000A, TLCS-90) and STMicroelectronics STM8. Work is in progress on supporting the Microchip PIC16 and PIC18 targets. It can be retargeted for other microprocessors.](http://sdcc.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

## CPM

[Continuous Phase Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_phase_modulation)

Answer (score 0):

## COG

Chip-on-glass. Refers to a technique where an integrated circuit is mounted on and integrated with a glass surface, to save space. This technique is commonly used for integrating a controller IC inside a display.

Answer (score 0):

## LVD

May refer to one of the following:

Low Voltage Detect. A detection mechanism used on microcontrollers, that generates a chip reset when the voltage falls below a given reference level.

Low Voltage Directive. The European directive 2006/95/EC which regulates the behavior of electrical devices with a supply voltage between 50V to 1000V AC, or 75V to 1500V DC.

Low Voltage Differential Signaling, see [LVDS](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/108639/6102).

Answer (score 0):

## PFM

Pulse Frequency Modulation.  Often generated by older mechanical systems that would send a single pulse for each rotation (or fraction) of a shaft.  A hall detector counting gear teeth is another common use.

Answer (score 0):

## CRO

Cathode Ray Oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

## SRPP

The acronym's meaning is [uncertain](http://www.tubecad.com/may2000/), but generally denotes a circuit with two triodes (tube or solid-state) connected such that the input triode's load is bootstrapped by the other triode, increasing the apparent impedance of the load seen by the input device.

Comment: [Article about SRPP](http://www.valvewizard2.webs.com/SRPP_Blencowe.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

## P-P

Multiple meanings:

- peak-to-peak, as in "the signal is 348V, p-p"
- push-pull, a type of amplifier configuration with a pair of devices. One device acts as a current source, the other as a current sink.

Answer (score 0):

## QVGA

Quarter Video Graphics Array, a 320 × 240 point graphics array (half each dimension of VGA, so a quarter the area or pixels) common in embedded systems that have less memory or processing power to drive a large display.

Answer (score 0):

### CC-II

Current Conveyor (second generation)

Answer (score 0):

## GIC

Generalized Impedance Converter

(A very versatile active circuit consisting of two operational amplifiers; primarily used in active filters and harmonic oscillators)

Answer (score 0):

## FDNR

Frequency Dependent Negative Resistor

(An active circuit consisting of two operational amplifiers; primary use in active filters)

Comment: Really!?  This is getting ridiculous.  Adding these kind of obscure abbreviations is getting absurd.

Answer (score 0):

## IMD

Intermodulation Distortion. A type of signal error (distortion) where two or more signals mix in a nonlinear circuit, resulting in new frequency components.

Answer (score 0):

## P1dB

Short for Output power at 1dB compression point. It is typically used when referring to Amplifiers. It is defined as the output power level at which the actual gain achieved deviates from the small signal gain by 1 dB.
 All active components have a linear dynamic range. This is the range over which the output power varies linearily with respect to the input power. As the output power increases to near its maximum capability, the device will begin to saturate. The point at which the saturation effects are 1 dB from linear, is defined as the 1 dB compression point.

Answer (score 0):

## UVM

[Universal Verification Methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Verification_Methodology) is a standardised method to verify Digital IP design by IEEE. It is generally conducted with SystemVerilog.

Answer (score -1):

## EMS

Electronic manufacturing services, companies that design, test, manufacture, distribute, and provide return/repair services for electronic components and assemblies for original equipment manufacturers (OEMs)

Comment: Too easy to confuse with electromagnetic spectrum and energy management systems.

Answer (score -1):

## MPU

Microprocessor or Multi-core processor or Memory protection

Comment: Which part of this is incorrect?

Comment: Check remarks #4 and #5 about voting on this question in the original question.

Comment: @jippie Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

## PM (modulation)

Short for "Phase Modulation"

Answer (score -1):

## PIC

May stand for 2 types of devices, which are not related to each-other.

- Peripheral Interface Controller.
- A family of micro-controllers from Microchip Technology.

Answer (score -1):

## j

Imaginary number. Math uses `i` but EE uses that letter to represent current.

Comment: Fun fact: Physicists use \$j\$ or \$I\$ for current because **\$i\$** is the imaginary unit. Adhering to the strange inverse convention in EE is akin to the strange adherence to the imperial units in the US.

Answer (score -1):

## i

I (or i): steady-state current

Sometimes i stands for instantaneous current.

Answer (score -1):

## PC

Program counter

Often used in microcontrollers when programming in assembly language.

Comment: Unfortunately, this could also be a Personal Computer or a Printed Circuit.

Comment: 1+ Commonly used enough that I think it belongs here

Comment: PC stands for [many things](http://www.abbreviations.com/pc) but I'd argue Program Counter is the most useful one to have on this site.

Answer (score -1):

## PM (control systems)

Phase margin (a stability measure for systems with feedback)

Answer (score -1):

## IP (Digital Design)

Intellectual property is the already developed module in HDL and is ready to be integrated into the system. [Some of them are open-source](https://opencores.org/) and the other needs to be purchased to use.

For example, [MicroBlaze](https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/microblaze.html) by Xilinx is an IP.

Comment: This definition doesn't feel right to me.  Things use IP or constitute IP, but I've never heard it said that something *is* IP

Comment: That's the reason why I add (Digital Design) at the end. It is the building block that is ready to use but you need to agree the license term from either the venders or open-source contributors to use it just like normal IPs other than Digital Designs as it can be their weeks of months of work. Like https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property.html or https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/programmable/intellectual-property.html, they all called IP or IP Cores. There are jobs to verify the IP with UVM. So I think IP (Digital Design) is a valid definition of it.

Answer (score -2):

## PPM

Pulse Position Modulation.

A modulation scheme widely used in optical communication in which the position of the carrier pulse is changed according to the information.

Comment: Also "parts per million"

Comment: and parts per million is the more common meaning *by far*, just think of resistors and references alone.