# What is the meaning of META?

Tags: discussion

I recently came across this part of the electrical engineering website and I see that it is used to report general bugs and issues with the website.  What I am wondering is the meaning of META.  What does it stand for?

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: The meaning of *meta* is roughly similar to *about*.  [See also here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta#About_.28its_own_category.29)

Comment: You can only ask about that on meta.meta.eese

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's a menu item "What's meta?" in the "help" menu. So, this question simply lacks basic research and doesn't have any benefit for the site or future readers.

Answer (score 1):

**Meaning**

[*Meta*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/meta) is often used when a higher level of abstraction is required. And *meta-X* often describe a *"X about a X"*. For example, *metadata* indicates data describing data, *meta-program* would be a program that program programs, *meta-joke* is a joke on a joke, and... *[hold your breath]* this very meta site is a Q&A site about the main EE.SE Q&A site.

**What is it for**

It is not only used to report general bugs and issues with the website. Discussions on meta can be very general and also address issues like:

- Is that kind of question on-topic/allowed on the main site?
- Why did this question got closed?
- How should I deal with this kind of posts?
- How to rationalize usage of these specific tags?
- How to behave in this specific situation?

There a are also purely informational posts, for example:

- [What are abbreviations used in electrical engineering?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/what-are-abbreviations-used-in-electrical-engineering)
- [Test the new LaTeX markdown in this Sandbox question!](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question)
- [Olin Lathrop facts](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5751/olin-lathrop-facts) (ehe... oops)

And, sometimes, some annoucements from stackexchange staff.

**Organization of stack exchange**

Each stack exchange site (stack overflow, electronics, whatever, ...) has its own meta, on which subjects specific to the specific main site are discussed. But when it becomes very generic and applicable to all sites, the [main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is actually more appropriate. And as a matter of fact, I think this very question (and also most "bugs and issues with the website", as you mentioned) should be better suited there, since it isn't only applicable to **electronics**.stackexchange.